# GAME Java random generator with cubes, while if do while

Tags: java, random

Lovely people,
I'm stuck with my java program. If i run my program it doesn't work how it is supposed to work. If computerSpeler throws 1 or 2x 1, it should be mensSpeler his turn. What is wrong with my program?

```java
import java.util.Random;

public class Spel {
    private EgbertComputerSpeler computerSpeler;
    private MensSpeler mensSpeler;
    private boolean mensSpelerBegint;
    public static final int HET_SPEL_IS_UIT_SCORE = 100;
    private int dobbelsteen1;
    private int dobbelsteen2;
    private Random generator = new Random();
    private int scoreComputer;
    private int scoreMens;
    private int worpen;
    private int beurt;

    public Spel() {
        computerSpeler = new EgbertComputerSpeler(HET_SPEL_IS_UIT_SCORE);
        mensSpeler = new MensSpeler(HET_SPEL_IS_UIT_SCORE);

        mensSpelerBegint = generator.nextBoolean();
    }

    public void dobbel() {
        dobbelsteen1 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;
        dobbelsteen2 = generator.nextInt(6) + 1;

        worpen = worpen + 1;
        beurt = beurt + dobbelsteen1 + dobbelsteen2;
    }

    public void speelSpel() {
        while (scoreMens <100 || scoreComputer < 100) {
            if (mensSpelerBegint) {
                do {
                    dobbel();

                    if (dobbelsteen1 == 1 && dobbelsteen2 == 1) {
                        scoreMens = scoreMens + 25 ;
                        mensSpelerBegint = false;
                    }

                    else if (dobbelsteen1 == 1 || dobbelsteen2 == 1) {
                        scoreMens = scoreMens + 0 ;
                        mensSpelerBegint = false;}
                } while (mensSpeler.wilGooien(false, worpen,
                                              scoreMens, scoreComputer));

                scoreMens = beurt + scoreMens;
                worpen = 0;
                beurt = 0;
            }

            else {
                do {
                    dobbel();

                    if (dobbelsteen1 == 1 && dobbelsteen2 == 1) {
                        scoreComputer = scoreComputer + 25;
                        mensSpelerBegint = true;}

                    else if (dobbelsteen1 == 1 || dobbelsteen2 == 1) {
                        scoreComputer = scoreComputer + 0;
                        mensSpelerBegint = true;}
                } while (computerSpeler.wilGooien(false, worpen,
                                                  scoreMens, scoreComputer));

                scoreComputer = beurt + scoreComputer;
                worpen = 0;
                beurt = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a puzzle :)

Comment: "If i run my program it doesn't work how it is supposed to work" -- we cannot know. Please edit your question and add: 1. *How* it does not work. Does it compile? Does it run? Do you get errors? (Do you get a blank screen with a blinking cursor in the top left corner?) 2. Describe what it does not but *should* do.

Comment: This is rather funny... This is written in Dutch, which I can read since Dutch is my first language, and from the writing I do recognise this as an exercise I had to do while in college, so my wild guess is that this is homework.

Comment: One of my students I tutored had similar homework .. But in German! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the code basically works like this (assuming I understand the code properly)

```
if turn == player:
    while player wants to continue:
        if bad stuff:
            turn = computer
else
    ....
endif
```

Yes, you're setting it to be the computer's turn, but it's still stuck in the `do-while` loop until `wilGooien` is set to false.

What you need to do is to `break;` out of the loop in addition to setting it to the computer's turn.